# Firebase project migration to new server changes to be made?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I am migrating my firebase project along with laravel and reactjs application to a new server with the same code and database. I am able to send push notfication to my live server from my application and receive it but not with migrating server. Able to receive FCM messages with migrating server when sent with testfcm.com a testing tool.I am developing some features for the existing mobileapp with a new release with someone else code with me just a newbie in app development.
I can see that same json data with service account and the server key is configured in the project. I am able to generate firebase token for the particular user in migrating server and when i create a push notification for the user, it sends it but unable to receive it in the tray or in the user profile.
this code gets executed when i send it from testfcm.com

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});

const unsubscribe = messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
      console.log('A new FCM message arrived!', JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
    });

    return unsubscribe;
```

But this code is executed when from application and nothing is caught on background handler or foreground

```
          case 'notification_channel':
        for (let i = 0; i < message.data.items.length; i++) {
          // store.dispatch(fetchCurrentNews(message.data.items[i].data.new_id))
          let title = _.get(message.data.items[i], 'data.notification.title');
          let body = _.get(message.data.items[i], 'data.notification.body');
          let type = _.get(message.data.items[i], 'data.data.type', '');
          let item_ids = _.get(message.data.items[i], 'data.data.item_ids', []).join(',');
          console.log("notification_channel "+JSON.stringify(message))
          me.notif.localNotif(body, title, {type, item_ids})
        }
        console.log('notification_channel')
        store.dispatch(fetchNotifications())
```

I am using emulator and am locally developing and changing the base or socket url either with live or migrating domain url and thats how i am able to deferentiate the changes

where can i see the log to find out what is the error? what else do i need to configure in the migrating server to get it working?

NB: this project is not configured and developed by me and dont have access to the person who developed it and been 1 to 2 weeks running behind it.

Tried with fcm tutorials and trying to find the logs for the real problem. Checked with the firebase console reports with no use

I am expecting to find the cause of error with the log and run the existing firebase project in migrated Server